# Speed of light measurement using a star mass, just like a satellite orbits the earth

Tags: gravity, spacetime, speed-of-light, orbital-motion

This is just an idea than came to my mind last night, would it be possible to, launch a satellite, close enough to the sun (To be safe for it) to light a laser, somewhere close enough to the sun, allowing the sun's mass to curve the light trajectory and making it go all around the sun, catching it back in the satellite, just as the laser were orbiting the sun, like this: [image: object orbiting the sun]

so after all it will be a one way light, and not an refection... Just asking

Comment: As I see it, this should be possible but probably something like a black hole would be better.

Comment: Photons only complete full orbits at the photon sphere. The sun's schwarzschild radius is roughly 2.9 km, making it's photon sphere about 4.35 km, all of this is well within the sun's current volume.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't possible near the Sun, it would require a black hole to make a beam of light go around in an orbit.

It also has the practical difficulty of determining what the distance traveled by the light is, because that close to a black hole both space and time are curved very sharply.

Seriously, the whole "one way speed of light" thing is a red herring. You can certainly measure the one way speed of light given a synchronization convention for clocks. The "problem" is that the synchronization convention is arbitrary -- if you really want to, you can choose a bizarre way of synchronizing clocks that makes the one way speed of light almost anything you want in some particular direction. But any practical and "natural" synchronization convention, such as "slow clock transport", is equivalent to Einstein's convention, in which the one way speed of light is $c$ in all directions.

Comment: Within a given inertial reference frame, simultaneity is absolute, so I'd think that two clocks in the same frame are either synchronized or not. But you say that "the synchronization convention is arbitrary", so you must be defining "synchronization" in a way that's completely foreign to me. Could you tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: How do you determine whether two distant clocks are synchronized or not? Or, equivalently, how do you synchronize them to start with? To do so you have to send signals between them, which means making assumptions about how fast the signals travel in the various directions. The simplest assumption is that the speed of light is the same in all directions, but you can equally well assume it is different in different directions and synchronize your clocks with that modified assumption.

Comment: Thanks, I see. But I'm not sure how you could justify such assumptions when we have experiments that have used slow clock transport and found that the upper limit on the anisotropy of the speed of light is tiny (as you seem to acknowledge). What's the point of even mentioning the possibility of assumptions that contradict empirical reality? Isn't that just a confusing distraction? Or is there some value in it that I'm not seeing?

Comment: As far as remote clock synchronization goes, "empirical reality" is what we define it to be. For example, you *could* define lines of simultaneity such that you add time when moving "west" and subtract when moving "east". If you follow this procedure for everything (including slow clock transport) the result is perfectly consistent but gives an anisotropic one way speed of light. Distant simultaneity is a matter of convention. The usual convention (giving isotropic speed of light) is the simplest. There's no reason *not* to use it...

Comment: ... but some people (inspired by a Youtube video) find it amazing that other conventions are possible and that we "can't" measure the one way speed of light. But really, it isn't a matter of measuring it, it's a matter of defining it. Frankly I think it's silly to define it to be anything other than the usual convention (half of the two way speed, the same in all directions) but if you really wanted to, you could -- and it would not contradict any experiment.

Comment: So if we defined it as $\frac c2$ one way and $\infty$ the other way, you say "it would not contradict any experiment", but wouldn't it contradict experiments that test the one-way speed using slow clock transport in various directions and find it to be almost exactly c in every direction? If we're still not understanding each other, feel free to create a chat if you're willing to hash this out with me. This topic has been making me crazy. :)

Comment: Slow clock transport also involves assumptions, since a moving clock (even one moving slowly) is subject to time dilation. How much time dilation it is subject to depends on the speed of light in the direction it is moving. Anyway, all of this is kind of moot, I definitely agree that the usual assumption (the speed of light is the same in all directions) is very much the simplest and most natural.